# Not selecting a row if substring of A is in string of B of one DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with "Employee Common Name" and "DisplayName" I would like to NOT select the row if the "Employee Common Name" is within the "DisplayName".

I have not found a way to do that yet but my current (failing) work around is to create a Boolean Column if the "Employee Common Name" is within the "DisplayName".

However everything is false.

Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Employee Common Name': ['Bob', 'Makenzie', 'Alice'], 
                   'DisplayName': ['Robert Inger', 'Kenzie Doe', 'Alice Cooper']})

df['Allowed']=df.apply(lambda x: str(df['Employee Common Name']) in str(df['DisplayName']).lower(), axis=1)
```

Expected Output:

| Employee Common Name | DisplayName | Allowed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Robert Inger | False |
| Makenzie | Kenzie Doe | False |
| Alice | Alice Cooper | True |

I already used str.strip() on 'Employee Common Name"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did good work, there is a tiny mistake. You never used x (the argument of your lambda function). Use x to access the current row instead of df (accessing the whole series).

Also, as pointed out in other answers and comment, you need to apply `.lower()` to either to both strings or to none of them.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Employee Common Name': ['Bob', 'Makenzie', 'Alice'], 
                   'DisplayName': ['Robert Inger', 'Kenzie Doe', 'Alice Cooper']})


df['Allowed'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x['Employee Common Name'].lower() in x['DisplayName'].lower(), axis=1
)
```

output as expected

[image]

Comment: This is true (and definitely a useful correction!) but also the root cause was the lack of `.lower()` being applied to Employee Common Name

Comment: thank you, I made an edit and highlighted this mistake, too.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you apply `.lower()` to only the display name, so it doesn't find "Alice" in "alice cooper". Try changing your code to

```
df['Allowed'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Employee Common Name'].lower() in x['DisplayName'].lower(), axis=1)
```

Comment: I changed both to .lower() and still get all false. Ah never mind, I just noticed I have to use x.  I thought it was not required

Comment: Yeah if you don't use x then the function will act on the whole dataframe every time instead of the individual rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can create (check if "Employee Common Name" is inside "DisplayName") and assign list to the new column:

```py
df["Allowed"] = [e in d for e, d in zip(df["Employee Common Name"], df["DisplayName"])]

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Employee Common Name   DisplayName  Allowed
0                  Bob  Robert Inger    False
1             Makenzie    Kenzie Doe    False
2                Alice  Alice Cooper     True
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along these lines will fit your needs?

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Employee Common Name': ['Bob', 'Makenzie', 'Alice'], 
                   'DisplayName': ['Robert Inger', 'Kenzie Doe', 'Alice Cooper']})

df['allowed'] = df['DisplayName'].str.contains("|".join(df['Employee Common Name']))
```

Where we are looking for sub-string matches in `DisplayName` if a string contains any substring in `Employee Common Name`,and the `|` indicates "OR".